# Could we set Launch screen in apple watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I have just started to explore about apple watch. Many objects those are available in iPhone but not in appleWatch like **progress bar** and much more. One more thing which I had searched about is splash screen, but couldn't find anything about how to set launch screen in apple watch.

Could anyone know about it?

Answer (score 2):

iWatch does not have splash screen or launch screen functionality...
iWatch auto detect app icon and show this icon for loading the application.

Comment: Sorry, you have no option for same.

Comment: @KRIMI I agree with Jogendar... there is no option to set our splash screen for a watch!!