# How can we add a launch screen to a watch app?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I am creating a watchOS app using SwiftUI and I wish to add a splash screen, but I am not sure whether it's possible. I have added the following to the Info.plist file, but doesn't seem to show a splash screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UILaunchScreen</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIImageName</key>
        <string>Rupee</string>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Sample</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CLKComplicationPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ComplicationController</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>google.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>Sample</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>Sample</string>
    </dict>
    <key>WKWatchOnly</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could we set Launch screen in apple watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062098/could-we-set-launch-screen-in-apple-watch)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ***(as of September 2021)***, WatchOS does not support a Launch Screen yet. I don't know if you noticed yet, but when an app launches on the watch, the app icon shows up with a progress view around it which is the default WatchOS launch screen for the apps and cannot be changed.

For more info: [Could we set Launch screen in apple watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062098/could-we-set-launch-screen-in-apple-watch)

Comment: Ohh yeah I noticed it once. So that means it's still not resolved. :(

Comment: Yeah. To help other users in the future that could have this question. Could you please mark the upvote and mark it as an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

For a fake launch screen, you can do something like this:

```
@State var shouldShowLaunchImage = true

var body: some View {
    ContentView()
        .overlay(
            Image("launch-image")
                .opacity(shouldShowLaunchImage ? 1 : 0)
        )
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                self.shouldShowLaunchImage = false
            }
        }
}
```